# What is the ':= ' operator?

Tags: solidity-0.6.x

I am familiar with the walrus operator `:=` [in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#new-features) but cannot understand its use in solidity.

A sample snippet is :

```
assembly { codehash := extcodehash(account) }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the the variable assignment operator in Yul. From the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/yul.html#assignments):

> Variables can be assigned to after their definition using the `:=`
> operator. It is possible to assign multiple variables at the same
> time. For this, the number and types of the values have to match. If
> you want to assign the values returned from a function that has
> multiple return parameters, you have to provide multiple variables.
> The same variable may not occur multiple times on the left-hand side
> of an assignment, e.g. `x, x := f()` is invalid.

The following function will return `4`:

```
function testFunction() public pure returns (uint result) {
    assembly {
        let v := 0            // value of v is 0 here
        v := 2                // value of v is 2 here
        result := add(v, 2)   // value of v is 4 here, so result = 4
    }
}
```

Your example is in [inline assembly](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/assembly.html) inside Solidity, `extcodehash` gets the code hash of address `account` and assign its value to the variable `codehash`.

Comment: Thanks for all the details. Just adding the reason behind "why is YUL needed for getting the code hash ? Couldn't it be done using solidity ?" -> The following example provides library code to access the code of another contract and load it into a bytes variable. **This is not possible with “plain Solidity”** and the idea is that reusable assembly libraries can enhance the Solidity language without a compiler change.

Comment: @PeDro Be careful, I think the part of the documentation you copied is not updated because in the current version of Solidity there are member types of address such as: `address.code` to get the code of an address and `address.codehash` to get the code hash of the address. So it is possible with plain Solidity since version `v0.8.0`. Info: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#address-related.